# Can I limit the results of an aws rds snapshot query to a certain timeframe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-backup

I have used the following query to find all rds snapshots, that were created after a certain date:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier db-identifier --snapshot-type awsbackup --query 'DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>=`Date`].{DBSnapshotIdentifier:DBSnapshotIdentifier,SnapshotCreateTime:SnapshotCreateTime}.sort_by(@,&SnapshotCreateTime)' --output json
```

What I am trying to do now, is to limit the result to within two hours of the desired point in time, e.g. >=`Date1`, but <=`Date2`.

My approach so far has been try to add a second argument to the query, like so:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier db-identifier --snapshot-type awsbackup --query 'DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>=`Date1`<=`Date2`].{DBSnapshotIdentifier:DBSnapshotIdentifier,SnapshotCreateTime:SnapshotCreateTime}.sort_by(@,&SnapshotCreateTime)' --output json
```

but this results in an empty list being returned.

Is what I am trying to do here even possible, without using jq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple in the end, different query conditions can easily be combined with a && operator. So in this case, the solution was:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier db-identifier --snapshot-type awsbackup --query 'DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>=`Date1`&&SnapshotCreateTime<=`Date2`].{DBSnapshotIdentifier:DBSnapshotIdentifier,SnapshotCreateTime:SnapshotCreateTime}.sort_by(@,&SnapshotCreateTime)' --output json
```